# How to set a body to mesh in andengine

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

Im going to create unique body with specifying vertices in Andengine

I have made a mesh with those vertices but have a problem in registering the body to the mesh

Eclispe underlines the last line of this snippet red:

```
Mesh UniqueBodyMesh = new Mesh(0, 0, MeshTriangles,UniqueBodyVerticesTriangulated.size(), DrawMode.TRIANGLES,this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
UniqueBodyMesh.setColor(1f, 0f, 0f);
mScene.attachChild(UniqueBodyMesh);
FixtureDef uniqueBodyFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(20f,0.5f, 0.5f);
Body uniqueBody = PhysicsFactory.createTrianglulatedBody(mPhysicsWorld,UniqueBodyMesh, UniqueBodyVerticesTriangulated,BodyType.DynamicBody, uniqueBodyFixtureDef);
mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(UniqueBodyMesh, uniqueBody));
```

[image]

I tried write a class that extends Mesh and implements IAreaShape and calculating the width and height of the shape using my own algorithm but it seems completely wrong and doesnt work

```
class myMesh extends Mesh implements IAreaShape
{

    private float mWidth;
    private float mHeight;

    float[] mBufferData;

    public myMesh(float pX, float pY, float[] pBufferData,
            int pVertexCount, DrawMode pDrawMode,
            VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager) {

        super(pX, pY, pBufferData, pVertexCount, pDrawMode, pVertexBufferObjectManager);
        mBufferData = pBufferData;
    }

    @Override
    public float getWidth() {
        float minX = 100000;
        float maxX = -100000;
        for(int i=0;i<mBufferData.length;i+=3)
        {
            if(mBufferData[i] < minX)
            {
                minX = mBufferData[i];
            }
            if(mBufferData[i] > maxX)
            {
                maxX = mBufferData[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Width : " + (maxX - minX));
        mWidth = maxX - minX;
        return mWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public float getHeight() {
        float minY = 100000;
        float maxY = -100000;
        for(int i=1;i<mBufferData.length;i+=3)
        {
            if(mBufferData[i] < minY)
            {
                minY = mBufferData[i];
            }
            if(mBufferData[i] > maxY)
            {
                maxY = mBufferData[i];
            }
        }

        this.mHeight = maxY - minY;
        return mHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public float getWidthScaled() {
        return getWidth();
    }

    @Override
    public float getHeightScaled() {
        return getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public void setHeight(float pHeight) {
        this.mHeight = pHeight;

    }

    @Override
    public void setWidth(float pWidth) {
        this.mWidth = pWidth;

    }

    @Override
    public void setSize(float pWidth, float pHeight) {
        setWidth(pWidth);
        setHeight(pHeight);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: You got any help for your problem or not? Otherwise I can provide you a help.

Comment: I found another solution for my problem using CodeAndWeb PhysicsEditor application but It would be gr8 if u can help me setting a body to a mesh.thank you

Comment: Wait for some time, I will provide you answer.

Comment: @ Siddharth Where is the Answer??